# Countdown Timer Adding Days React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to achieve making a countdown timer of 14 days and it should not reset when you refresh the page. I already did it but the problem is I don't know how to add the date now + 14 days any ideas on how it can be done. Thank you really appreciate your help.

This is my code:

```
const Timer = () => {
  const [timerDays, setTimerDays] = useState("00");
  const [timerHours, setTimerHours] = useState("00");
  const [timerMinutes, setTimerMinutes] = useState("00");
  const [timerSeconds, setTimerSeconds] = useState("00");

  let interval = useRef();

  const startTimer = () => {
    const countdownDate = new Date("Jan 17, 2021 00:00:00").getTime();

    interval = setInterval(() => {
      const now = new Date().getTime();
      const distance = countdownDate - now;

      const days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
      const hours = Math.floor(
        (distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60)
      );
      const minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
      const seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

      if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(interval.current);
      } else {
        setTimerDays(days);
        setTimerHours(hours);
        setTimerMinutes(minutes);
        setTimerSeconds(seconds);
      }
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const someref = interval.current;
    startTimer();
    return () => {
      clearInterval(someref);
    };
  }, []);
};
```

Comment: @codemonkey u have any idea on how to make countdown timer that doesn't reset even if the browser is refreshed?

Comment: Can you add some sample code, we may help you. The problem is so unclear.

Comment: Start the countdown on the server and then call an API to check where the countdown is at any point in time.

Comment: Why did you edit the question and remove the code? Your previous question was much more detailed than this.

Comment: @yudhiesh Yeah but it was also a completely different question.

Comment: Sample code plz what you try

Comment: here is my sample code

Comment: here this is my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a way to keep time persistent in local storage because you want to use the timer even after browser refresh happend. so here is what you need to do:

```
const Timer = () => {
  const [timerDays, setTimerDays] = useState("00");
  const [timerHours, setTimerHours] = useState("00");
  const [timerMinutes, setTimerMinutes] = useState("00");
  const [timerSeconds, setTimerSeconds] = useState("00");

  let interval = useRef();

  const startTimer = (countdownDate) => {
    const now = new Date().getTime();
    const distance = countdownDate - now;

    const days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    const hours = Math.floor(
      (distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60)
    );
    const minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    const seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    if (distance < 0) {
      clearInterval(interval.current);
    } else {
      setTimerDays(days);
      setTimerHours(hours);
      setTimerMinutes(minutes);
      setTimerSeconds(seconds);
    }
  };

  function saveInLocalStorage(time) {
    localStorage.setItem("timer", time);
  }

  function getTimeFromLocalStorage() {
    return localStorage.getItem("timer");
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const localTimer = getTimeFromLocalStorage();

    if (localTimer) {
      interval.current = setInterval(() => {
        startTimer(+localTimer);
      }, 1000);
    } else {
      const countdownDate = new Date().getTime() + 14 * 24 * 60 * 1000;
      saveInLocalStorage(countdownDate);
      interval.current = setInterval(() => {
        startTimer(+countdownDate);
      }, 1000);
    }

    return () => clearInterval(interval.current);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      timerDays: {timerDays} &nbsp; timerHours: {timerHours} &nbsp;
      timerMinutes: {timerMinutes} &nbsp; timerSeconds: {timerSeconds} &nbsp;
    </div>
  );
};
```

here is a working demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-sammet-9zj32?file=/src/App.js:84-1823

Comment: Hi thanks for answering my problem this is what I wanted but the countdown doesn't move do u know the reason for this thanks again

Comment: @AlifKhan My bad, I've mistakenly used `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`, so I've changed My answer and add a demo for you to see,

Answer (score 0):

Use LocalStorage.
Hope this works.

```
const Timer = () => {
    const [timerDays, setTimerDays] = useState(localStorage.getItem('days')?localStorage.getItem('days'):0);
    const [timerHours, setTimerHours] = useState(localStorage.getItem('hours')?localStorage.getItem('days'):0);
    const [timerMinutes, setTimerMinutes] = useState(localStorage.getItem('minutes')?localStorage.getItem('days'):0);
    const [timerSeconds, setTimerSeconds] = useState(localStorage.getItem('seconds')?localStorage.getItem('days'):0);
  
    let interval = useRef();
  
    const startTimer = () => {
      let countdownDate;
      if(timerDays || timerHours || timerMinutes || timerSeconds)
        countdownDate = new Date(timerDays,timerHours,timerMinutes,timerSeconds).getTime();
    else countdownDate = new Date("Jan 17, 2021 00:00:00").getTime();
  
      interval = setInterval(() => {
        const now = new Date().getTime();
        const distance = countdownDate - now;
  
        const days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        const hours = Math.floor(
          (distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60)
        );
        const minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        const seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
  
        if (distance < 0) {
          clearInterval(interval.current);
          localStorage.removeItem('days');
          localStorage.removeItem('hours');
          localStorage.removeItem('minutes');
          localStorage.removeItem('seconds');
        } else {
          setTimerDays(days);
          setTimerHours(hours);
          setTimerMinutes(minutes);
          setTimerSeconds(seconds);
          localStorage.setItem('days',days);
          localStorage.setItem('hours',hours);
          localStorage.setItem('minutes',minutes);
          localStorage.setItem('seconds',seconds);
        }
      });
    };
  
    useEffect(() => {
      const someref = interval.current;
      startTimer();
      return () => {
        clearInterval(someref);
      };
    }, []);
  };
```

Comment: Hi thanks for ur answer it is working but when I refresh all of the time become 0

Comment: I have to refresh 2 times to make it go back